# Receiving partial messages when using VirtualWire and ServoTimer2

Tags: servo, rf, virtualwire

I'm writing a project where an Arduino board that is connected to a servo engine receives commands from another Arduino. The possible commands are:

1. Move 10 degrees
2. Reset position
3. Sweep until you're told to stop

My problem is with the sweep-mode, when I get the sweep command, I get into a while loop, that first checks for a sweep-terminator and then sweeps.

```
} else if (message == sweep) {
  Serial.println("sweep");
  while (msg1 != sweep_term) {
    // set the direction for the servo to move
    if (val == 750){
      val = 2250;
    } else {
      val = 750;
    }

    // move the servo
    myservo.write(val);
    // wait for the servo to move
    delay(15);

    // wait for a message
    if (vw_get_message(buf1, &buflen1)) {
      buf1[buflen1] = '\0';
      msg1 = (char*)buf1;
      memset(buf1,'0',VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN);
      Serial.print(buflen1);
      Serial.print(" [sweep] Got: ");
      Serial.println(msg1);
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, when I'm in this loop I don't get the sweep terminator message, or I get a part of it. I suspect that the servo is responsible for this, since when I run the same program without `myservo.write()`s I *do* receive those terminators.

Comment: What do you imagine that `memset(buf1,'0',VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN);` does?

Comment: @jwpat7, fills buf1 with zeros? It wasn't intended to be null-terminator or anything else. msg1 is a of type `String`, not `char *`

Comment: @Quaker You're filling the string with VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN zero characters - it's ending up as "000000000....000".  '0' is the character 0 as if you had typed it on your keyboard, not ASCII character code 0 or the NULL character.

Comment: Please post the data types for `msg1` and `buf1`.

Comment: `I suspect that the servo is responsible for this` - can you run the code, with the `myservo.write()` but **without** the servo physically connected. This will eliminate a possible electrical problem.

Comment: @NickGammon, I will try that. `msg1` is a `String` while `buf1` is a `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Majenko, I didn't understand your comment. AFAIK there are only two options, 0 as a number and 0 as an ASCII character, what is the 3rd option you suggested?

Comment: @Quaker NULL is 0 as a number - used to denote the end of a string.  It's known as the "NULL Terminating Character".  You are using "0 as an ASCII character" when you should be using "0 as a number *to denote the NULL terminating character*".

Comment: @Majenko, no I don't. That wasn't my intention and I clearly stated in the second comment that `It wasn't intended to be null-terminator`. When I wanted to terminate the string I did it as in `buf1[buflen1] = '\0';`, while when I used `memset()` I only wanted to overwrite the whole buffer with a constant character, it could have been 'Z' or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply connected the servo to an external power 5V power source, and everything works perfectly fine. It seems like the servo's resistance was too much for the RF receiver to be able to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

If `msg1` is of type `char*` (as is implied by the cast in `msg1 = (char*)buf1;`), then it seems to me that that statement will copy the address of `buf1` to `msg1`.  Then, when you fill `buf1` with ascii zeroes (ie, characters `'0'`) `msg1` ends up being a string of ascii zeroes.

On the other hand, if `msg1` is of type `String` (to go along with your comment about `buf1` being of type `String`) the cast should be unnecessary.

Note, if you don't give the source for the `vw_get_message()` routine and the declarations for all of the constants and variables used in the code extract, it's unlikely anyone can definitively answer your question.

Note, the `while` test, `msg1 != sweep_term`, may not be well-defined on entry to the while loop.  Or, if `msg1` is left over from a previous use, you won't enter the loop at all.  Consider writing the loop in the form `do { ... } while (msg1 != sweep_term);` instead.

Note, if (as said in a comment) `buf1` is of type `String`, then the statement `memset(buf1,'0',VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN);` is a line of code I'd recommend against, because it treats `buf1` as a simple array rather than as an object.  (In this case it *should* make no difference, but it requires some research to be sure of that. [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422830/structure-of-a-c-object-in-memory-vs-a-struct),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects),[3](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus),[4](http://databasefaq.com/index.php/answer/111791/c-c-11-move-which-rules-determine-whether-an-object-is-trivially-copyable),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034121/what-will-happen-on-memcpy-of-structures-with-c-string)])

Comment: It seems likely buf1 is uint8_t judging by this prototype:  `uint8_t  vw_get_message (uint8_t *buf, uint8_t *len)`

Comment: `buf1` is indeed a `uint8_t` and `msg1` is a `String`. I thought that assigning a `char *` string to a `String` copies it (as in C#) and not just copying the pointer.

Comment: Could it be that the movement of the engine is blocking the RF receiver from receiving the message that is being sent while it's working?

Comment: I'm reading online that there are a lot of problems with receiving RF signals while servo is running. When the signal wire of servo is disconnected my code works fluently, but when it is connected and the engine is running - the troubles starts. Any suggestion?

Comment: For problem diagnosis, you could try powering different systems (such as Arduino, radio, and servos) with isolated and well-bypassed power supplies, and make all connections with short, soldered-in-place wires.  (See eg [seattlerobotics](http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/jun97/basics.html) re bypassing.)  Have a 10 or 20 uF cap connected where power goes onto each board, and 0.001 or 0.01 uF caps from each power line to ground, to prevent electrical noise from spreading via power supply connections.  You may need to enclose the radio (except its antenna) in a metal case.

Comment: If you can temporarily substitute a wired connection in place of the radio connection, that would allow you to check out your code and perhaps decide if problems are mostly hardware or mostly software.